# How to solve .mps model using Watson Machine Learning rest API?

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, cplex

I am trying to solve .mps model with REST API from Postman but unable to get the result.

I have created, uploaded and deployed the model with Watson Machine Learning rest API and now trying to run it. But getting below error
"errors": [
{
"code": "PROCESSING",
"message": "Unexpected CAMS communication issue accessing attachment 'm1' for job '35a569b6-e30e-451b-b2d9-22239d24651c' due to 'Unsupported asset type:wml_model'."
}

I am able to solve it using UI (Watson studio)
I dont know where I am wrong. Might be I am not passing the correct input to (https://eu-de.ml.cloud.ibm.com/ml/v4/deployment_jobs/....) which requires json format.

Does anyone know how to do it (through REST API)

Thanks & Regards,
Swati Kaup

Comment: My best guess is you are uploading or specifying the wrong type of model. Check the supported model/asset type from here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/4.8.x?topic=specifications-supported-frameworks-software. My approach would be reverse engineer what is the model type specified in watson studio.